# Visual Studio 2013,error "Expression must have a class type"

Tags: c++-cli

I create an project with Visual Studio--C++--CLR, and I am trying to create a small login page which have two textbox and two label and button like everyone else.

After I put everything I am trying to put some code in button "login" like this

```
string str = userNameInput.Text;  // userNameInput is a textBox
```

and it shows me an error `"Expression must have a class type"`

Can anyone explain how this happened?

Comment: It resulting if I use"String^ username = userNameInput->Text;" then there is no more error. I want to know why. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `userNameInput` is pointer.
The error implies that it is and your line should be:  `userNameInput->Text`

Comment: you can read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) for more information, it is the syntax (in both C and C++)  to access the data of the object which is in the address the pointer contain.